# How to Get the Least significant Bit in Apex?

Tags: apex, code

Like in Java we have a function Integer.lowestOneBit(i) or return I & -i.

Does Salesforce support it or not, If there is an Alternative?

Answer (score 2):

`Integer`, `Decimal`, and `Long` don't have a `lowestOneBit` method. However, you can use `i & -i` in Apex. The `|`, `&`, and `~` operators have the same behavior as you'd expect in any other language that supports Boolean bit operators.